# Email ends up in spam but only when sending from live website. Localhost works

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I'm using a thirdparty SMTP service - [turboSMTP](http://www.serversmtp.com/)

And I use it when sending emails from both localhost(when testing) and from the live website and both of them work. But the email sent from the **live website always get flagged as spam**, while **the email from  localhost is not flagged as spam**.

Even if the sender email is the same. The content is the same. the title is the same and so on.

Does it actually see that I'm sending from a live website or from localhost when I'm sending through a third party SMTP service that isn't related to my webhost?

a cut from my code :

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(sender);
mailMessage.To.Add(recipient);
mailMessage.Subject = title;
mailMessage.Body = message;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

smtpClient.Host = "smtpAddress";
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Email that got flagged as spam(Sent from live website)

```
Delivered-To: censoredAddress@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.132.3 with SMTP id g3csp14274iod;
        Thu, 4 Dec 2014 00:02:36 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.202.225.197 with SMTP id y188mr5614041oig.94.1417680156083;
        Thu, 04 Dec 2014 00:02:36 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <noreply@censoredDomain.se>
Received: from tbjjbihbhcbji.turbo-smtp.net (tbjjbihbhcbji.turbo-smtp.net. [199.187.172.198])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id x10si17295964oek.84.2014.12.04.00.02.35
        for <censoredAddress@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 04 Dec 2014 00:02:36 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of noreply@censoredDomain.se does not designate 199.187.172.198 as permitted sender) client-ip=199.187.172.198;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of noreply@censoredDomain.se does not designate 199.187.172.198 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@censoredDomain.se;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@
Message-Id: <5480151c.8a283c0a.71e4.678eSMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=censoredDomain.se; s=turbo-smtp; x=1418284956; h=DomainKey-Signature:
    Received:Received:MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:
    Content-Transfer-Encoding; bh=7vEAgi0RRzjrn+4Le/fcS1k1+tJ/Ro6XDU
    4TKOlZ0JY=; b=Yu5q4UjDuGv2L/Fa3MR+FO4+h3jWj5KHKvDGZFCyJYj0+aB7aV
    kgOix5W5zrlaJ0rbl39Ck08AORmO82jdcXzFdtFm5lst6ENG3JaWorxWyxduqWBI
    TY7ZSzs9HJb4TBXcMQvvaPdM96VA7FP3i4vb4Q9mkoGX1nD6c9asLirsE=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
    s=turbo-smtp; d=censoredDomain.se;
    h=Received:Received:X-TurboSMTP-Tracking:MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    b=ttGj0ZR2T0aPVS+Q+0oEdy5VM4wWzIBm2DtLYvtUFyHhldqWO5n2kVnZN3m1pR
    w0gGFX/r67i9FblNhg04ELxvsfO2+mHg0bhyTJgYOAPjS0DjoMBZI1WD2w/CTObN
    VMxSkTu8Hq8CDe49SRsduLnVLUdg2zwt86eNxItLLTno0=;
Received: (qmail 1442 invoked from network); 4 Dec 2014 08:02:34 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO Irwindale) (authenticated@212.247.113.26)  by turbo-smtp.com with SMTP; 4 Dec 2014 08:02:34 -0000
X-TurboSMTP-Tracking: 1692405204
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: noreply@censoredDomain.se
To: censoredAddress@gmail.com
Date: 4 Dec 2014 09:02:34 +0100
Subject: Testar igen
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

asdasdasd
```

Email that did **not** get flagged as spam(Sent from localhost)

```
Delivered-To: censoredAddress@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.132.3 with SMTP id g3csp14413iod;
        Thu, 4 Dec 2014 00:03:46 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.60.150.194 with SMTP id uk2mr5861322oeb.37.1417680226570;
        Thu, 04 Dec 2014 00:03:46 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <noreply@censoredDomain.se>
Received: from tbjjbihbhcbji.turbo-smtp.net (tbjjbihbhcbji.turbo-smtp.net. [199.187.172.198])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id a140si17357087oib.49.2014.12.04.00.03.45
        for <censoredAddress@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 04 Dec 2014 00:03:45 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of noreply@censoredDomain.se does not designate 199.187.172.198 as permitted sender) client-ip=199.187.172.198;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=fail (google.com: domain of noreply@censoredDomain.se does not designate 199.187.172.198 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@censoredDomain.se;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@
Message-Id: <54801561.924dca0a.a7bc.ffffe533SMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=censoredDomain.se; s=turbo-smtp; x=1418285025; h=DomainKey-Signature:
    Received:Received:MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:
    Content-Transfer-Encoding; bh=7vEAgi0RRzjrn+4Le/fcS1k1+tJ/Ro6XDU
    4TKOlZ0JY=; b=rW/7YJz7bCAsSz8EF2NTfU+JbIsh5A4QLAQ5EgrxJUG3j1vJmt
    8aVAMEI+45iC79T/vFpfLrN1e+fuSXCXuiw9MhTgBvHG0w0JIiKpufyHUnIRmNUs
    YjNRErfIhaHwtEgAFXL/0ou0sG7QrG2cKu8VP/P2WA7opvoC6tfgIQH6k=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
    s=turbo-smtp; d=censoredDomain.se;
    h=Received:Received:X-TurboSMTP-Tracking:MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    b=o5Vxv9MAQeyFm1EqkQ3f56XVgxzSOR2HNB7oqg6GqxP4qPy8QY9hBu2w5DPdf3
    8d/HQqJX61zN4Rfnyxgrw2PMPXr5dsrpKnKyB3o1/FsGCLH3meLyO+LYxeQBLRFO
    kKtUtQ4vvSy2TN+7Sefe18lQo+E6bUunTcg64kw2I//4E=;
Received: (qmail 11732 invoked from network); 4 Dec 2014 08:03:45 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO Codecomp-HP) (authenticated@78.70.27.139)  by turbo-smtp.com with SMTP; 4 Dec 2014 08:03:45 -0000
X-TurboSMTP-Tracking: 1692407529
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: noreply@censoredDomain.se
To: censoredAddress@gmail.com
Date: 4 Dec 2014 09:03:39 +0100
Subject: Testar igen
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

asdasdasd
```

Comment: Where do you send the mail to? Gmail, Outlook with internal Spam filter, ...? Can you post the headers of both mails? In Gmail you can view them via "Show original" in the menu opening with the "down arrow" in the top right corner...

Comment: They are sent to the same email address, which is a gmail one. is the header all the information except for the content or is there a specific part you want?

Comment: Please share the complete headers (you can replace addresses and hostnames with generic names if you like)...

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? If so maybe that server has been blacklisted because of someone else using it for spamming. If so try contacting your host to see if they can unblock it. This happened to me once and they fixed it within a couple of days once it had propagated.

Comment: @ChrFin I posted the whole emails

Comment: @demoncodemonkey I believe it is being shared. But I don't see how it should affect it when it is a third party SMTP service that actually sends the emails. or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is the same when using a 3rd party service, but I had similar issues and had to add an SPF record to my domain to ensure it was not marked as spam. if it works from local host it may be because the domain and email come from the same IP so it could be automatically authenticated.

Comment: I wound up here in the process of investigating how many others have trouble with turbosmtp as a spam source - just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) fail in you mails:

> spf=fail (google.com: domain of noreply@censoredDomain.se does not designate 199.187.172.198 as permitted sender)

Try adding the IP address (range) of the SMTP provider to your SPF record (or remove it completely).

You get that fail on both mails, so I do not know why one gets through, but the one failing is probalby caused by the SPF check.

Also the DKIM signature seems to be not correct:

> dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@

You should check that with the SMTP provider.

Comment: I'm gonna check these out but might take a while if I have to contact my hosting but will set it as the answer if it works later